# Remove Padding with SlideToogle

Tags: css

I have some code that expands the rows. The table has padding for each td. Which is fine but the table when collapsed still shows this padding,

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/55/

Below is the **jquery**

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {


        var $children = $(this).nextUntil( $('tr').not('[class^=child-]') );
        $children.find('td > div').slideToggle();
});

$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div').hide();
```

Below is the **HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="parent" id="row1">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1-2">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="row2">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row2-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row2-1">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="row3">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row3-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row3-2">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to ensure that the padding is removed when the rows are collapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i'm sure you've figured out that the problem is the `padding` that bootstrap is appliyng to the `<td>`.

On the other hand, if you toggle the slide on the `<td>`, it gets weird because it does not hide the div's overflow.

**An easy fix for that is to toggle both (td and div), simultaneously:**

```
$children.find('td > div, td').slideToggle();
```

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/58/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you hide the `<div>`s inside the `<td>`s, not the `<td>`s themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that matches your needs is simply to add a class called "td-padding" and toggle it just like you toggle the slide`$('tr[class^=child-]').toggleClass(".td-padding");`

You must also remove the padding declaration
 `.table th, .table td {
    padding: 5px;
}` 
that you had. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Papibarozza/0Lh5ozyb/46/

The padding that remains is built into the HTML element itself (called border-spacing in agent user stylesheet in chrome devtools).

This leads onto my next point I want to make. Are you sure you really need to implement this with a table and tablecells? I'd suggest you to use a list instead since and UL within an UL has a logic child-parent relationship. A lot of your coding goes to distinguish this, with a lot of classnames and complexity as a result. With UL>UL relationship you could just call `$(".parent").children()` on a clicked element. The padding could be completely customized then aswell.

Comment: Thanks but the example, with the padding is based on the style that comes from bootstrap styling for tables.
Ive updated the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/56/

Bootstrap is forcing padding plus your are hidding the div's not the `td` element which has the `padding`

---

```js
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {
        
        
        var $children = $(this).nextUntil( $('tr').not('[class^=child-]') );
        $children.find('td > div').slideToggle();
        
        
});

$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div').hide().css({});
```

```css
td {padding:0px!important;}
td div{padding:5px}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr class="" id="">
        <td><div>People TEST</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand TEST</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A TEST</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="">
        <td><div>People TEST</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand TEST</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A TEST</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="row1">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1-2">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="row2">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row2-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row2-1">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent" id="row3">
        <td><div>People</div></td>
        <td><div>Click to Expand</div></td>
        <td><div>N/A</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row3-1">
        <td><div>Eve</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row3-2">
        <td><div>John</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to the parent row and remove the padding for its td.

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/0Lh5ozyb/59/

`$children.find('td > div').slideToggle().parents('tr').toggleClass('open');`